# "Unrecognized expression `$regexMatch`" in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I was trying to use the aggregate operator with mongoose and was getting the following error:

> "Unrecognized expression `$regexMatch`"

```
let data = await Product.aggregate([
            { $match: { product_name: { $regex: /iphone/i } } },
            {
                $project: {
                    product_name: 1,
                    is_starting_match: {
                        $regexMatch: { input: '$product_name', regex: /^iphone/i },
                    },
                    price: {
                        $convert: {
                            input: { $arrayElemAt: ['$stores.storePrice', 0] },
                            to: 'int',
                            onError: 0,
                            onNull: 0,
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
            { $sort: { price: -1 } },
        ]);
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question, your question is not cleat as per your title and question detail, add more details with mongodb version, and your query looks good.